# Jensen's inequality in Collaborative Topic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, variational-bayes, latent-dirichlet-alloc, approximate-inference

I am reading the article [Collaborative Topic Modeling for Recommending Scientific Articles](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/papers/WangBlei2011.pdf) and could notice the application of Jensen's inequality in order to define a bound from which optimization is done w.r.t. the mixture of proportions $\theta_{j}$. The task is to learn the mixture proportions. I understand how Jensen's inequality works, but for this specific example I seem to not be able to fully understand its derivation, i.e, the intuition behind and the conditions that allowed the authors to use such approach. Thus, can some one provide both some intuition for the inequality usage (I want to check whether my reasoning is correct) and some explicit derivation on how to arrive at the paper's equation (10)?

Explicitly, from equation (7):

$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{\lambda_{u}}{2} \sum_{i}u_{i}^{T}u_{i} -\frac{\lambda_{v}}{2} \sum_{j} (v_{j}-\theta_{j})^{T}(v_{j}-\theta_{j}) + \sum_{j}\sum_{n}\log(\sum_{k}\theta_{jk}\beta_{k,w_{jn}}) - \sum_{ij}\frac{c_{ij}}{2}(r_{ij} - u_{i}^{T}v_{j})^{2}.$$

Then, separating the terms containing $\theta_{j}$, defining $q(z_{jn} = k) = \phi_{jnk}$, and applying Jensen's inequality arrive at:

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta_{j}) \geq -\frac{\lambda_{v}}{2} \sum_{j} (v_{j}-\theta_{j})^{T}(v_{j}-\theta_{j}) + \sum_{n}\sum_{k} \phi_{jnk}\left( \log\left (\theta_{jk}\beta_{k,w_{jn}}\right) -\log\left(\phi_{jnk}\right) \right).$$

General questions for discussion:

- What is the motivation for the form of $q(z_{jn} = k)$?
- How can I prove that the optimal $\phi_{jnk}$ satisfies $\phi_{jnk} \propto \theta_{jk}\beta_{k,w_{jn}}$? (Paper's equation (11))

I have been searching for some clues on papers whose citation index includes (Wang and Blei 2011), but all I could find was some repeated description of the approximation procedure with little to none addition of explanation. Can someone help on this?

Comment: You have copied the second formula incorrectly in several respects.  First, either the left hand side or the equality sign is wrong.  Second, there is no summation inside the $\log$ on the r.h.s.  There may be other problems, but those two are the ones I spotted first.

Comment: @jbowman sorry! my mistake when copying and pasting the Latex! Fixed now! Thanks!